# USB device gives error -32

Tags: usb, android

I have a Samsung phone that I am trying to connect to a PC (Windows 7 and Debian) and I get messages indicating that the phone is not being recognized by USB. I have already installed the requisite drivers from Samsung Corp as well as ADB, Heimdall, and Odin. I used multiple cables and all different USB ports on three different laptops and desktop PCs with the same result. It once worked flawlessly on a Toshiba laptop that I no longer have access to. This has always happened since buying the phone (Samsung 9195), but now I actually really need to connect it for servicing.

dmesg is showing this:

```
usb 2-1-port4: attempt power cycle
usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.4: device not accepting address 19, error -32
usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 20 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.4: device not accepting address 20, error -32
usb 2-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

What can the problem be?

Comment: have you tried a different USB cable?

Comment: @Keltari He says he has tried multiple cables in the question ...